# Free hosting plan on windows azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have a plan to deploy my two java webapps on Windows Azure Cloud. My apps are resource extensive and require atleast 1.5GB RAM each.I Want to ask how much physical memory (RAM) they offer for an instance of app during 3 month Trial Period so I can decide about the future of my Apps. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smallest instance has 1.75 GB RAM.  That can be scaled up on an is-needed basis.  See http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/ for more details